# nginx rewrite root to subfolder

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm running a headless wordpress cms with static Vue frontend. The wordpress site is in the root folder and the Vue files are in the /dist folder.

I'm trying to setup rewrite rules so all traffic is rewritten to the /dist folder which serves the static site but allows the wp-json, wp-admin and wp-admin to be accessible too.

The rewrite rules logic should be :

- `if the location contains wp-json, rewrite to /index.php`
- `else if the file exists, dont rewrite anything (to allow wp-admin, wp-content to work)`
- `else attempt to rewrite to a file in the dist folder if the file exists, e.g. /css/app.css should rewrite to /dist/css/app.css`
- `else rewrite url to /dist/index.html?$1 (to allow vue router to work)`

I've got the following so far, but its not ideal, how can i improve it? should i be using try_files ?

```
location ~* /wp-json/?(.*) {
     rewrite ^/wp-json/?(.*) /index.php break;
}
location /wp-admin {
        break;
}
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|json|svg|mp4)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /dist/$1 break;
}
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /dist/index.html?$1 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

took a few mins to read the docs on try_files and worked it out pretty easily then

```
location /wp-json {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location /wp-admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ break;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri @dist;
}
location @dist {
    try_files $uri /dist/$uri @vue;
}
location @vue {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /dist/index.html?$1 break;
}
```